# How to validate a user's password, with a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I'm making a bash script for the Ubuntu Terminal. I need to verify the user before the code can continue. How do I ask and validate their existing log-in password?

Comment: You could put it in a directory accessible only for a certain group, then add the directory to the global path, then add those users to said group.

Comment: Unless this is a password specific to your application, don't get involved; let the program that needs the password do the verification.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is unclear what you actually try to do from the current state of your question. Is that a password specific for your application? Against what should that password be validated? So what is the authority here? Why don't you use the usual approach and delegate things like authorization to the parts of the systems that offer a service for such thing, like the PAM system for example?

Comment: I believe that OP's intentions become clear in the last question. He is trying to ask the user for his current password and then check if this password matches his current one. Imagine the first part of invoking `su`

Comment: The PAM Application Developers Guide includes a short C program which does almost exactly what you want, as a brief example of how to use PAM. (Chapter 8 of the ADG, which you will find in `/usr/share/doc/libpam-doc/html/Linux-PAM_ADG.html` if you have installed `libpam-doc`.). If you are comfortable with C programming, you should be able to modify it to do exactly what you want. (And someone might have already done that, but I don't know where the result would be.)

Comment: Crossposting: http://askubuntu.com/q/758185/336375

Answer (score 2):

You could always just use the `id` command and do something like:

```
user=$(id -u) # Set $user to user's user id
```

If you do that in your script, then you can check if `$user` is a valid user id.  You can look at user names and ids in the `/etc/group` file.  Of course, this is not validating the user's password.  Rather, this just checks the id of the user running the script.

Comment: It is not safer if you include the possibility that someone has grabbed the terminal while the logged-in user was AFK for a few seconds, which is why "change my password" dialogs tend to require you to enter your password even though you are currently logged in.

Comment: @rici Good point, I suppose that is true.  I was just saying that it might be safer than prompting the user to re-enter their password, unless of course it's an encrypted connection.

Comment: Does anyone still use telnet these days?

Comment: @rici they really shouldn't be, it's a horrible idea.  Yet the fact that it still comes preinstalled on many unix based OS's tells me some people still use it unfortunately.  Maybe to log into to really old servers/routers?  Who knows.

Anyone, I'll recant my statement saying that my solution is "safer".  I was just trying to give OP a quick solution that may have been simpler than the route OP was going.  Using that `id` command like that to check user ids is pretty common in scripts/services.

Comment: The telnet utility is still useful, I guess -- I used it a few months ago to test an SMTP server, for example -- but the telnet daemon which you would need to run to accept telnet shell connections doesn't seem to be preinstalled any more. But your answer is much better. +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
getent shadow | cut -d ":" -f 2
```

If it returns `!!`, no password set, otherwise, user has password.

Following this, we can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

for user in $(getent shadow | cut -d ":" -f 1);
do
  has_pass=$(getent shadow | grep $user | cut -d ":" -f 2)
    if [ $has_pass = "!!" ]; then
      echo "User $user does not have password"
    else
      echo "User $user has password"
    fi
done
```

Anyways, next time, at least, try to do something before asking.

Comment: How does this validate the password?

Comment: @rici it basically says if the user has a password or not.. You can instead set the output to 1 or 0 and make use of the value somehow

Comment: This in no way validates the user's password. It only checks to see if one exists.